# extending ko.viewmodel on each array element fails

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-viewmodel-plugin

I can create a View Model such that an array of clickable div's, with favorite/nonfavorite type icons, works correctly. I use knockout to bind the css style, which has the appropriate background image set.
The Favorite function is this:

```
function Favorite() {

  var self = this;
  self.isFavorite = ko.observable();
  self.toggleMe = function(ctx) {
    self = ctx;
    var val = self.isFavorite();
    self.isFavorite(!val);
  };
  self.isFavoriteClass = ko.computed(function() {

    if (self.isFavorite() === true)
      return 'favorite';
    else
      return 'notFavorite';
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="css: {favorite: isFavorite()==true, 
                      notFavorite: !isFavorite() }  ,
                      event: {click: toggleMe}" 
                      style="border:solid red;">

</div>
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LEwQd544rxrzhNyoyO5F?p=preview

However, I want to achieve the same effect with the ko.viewmodel plugin. (Well, I'd like to also be able to do is with ko.mapping :-) )  ko.viewmodel plugin reference is here:
http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/

The syntax for extending view models created with ko.viewmodel is very simple. Here is their example:

```
options:{ 
    extend:{
        "{root}.users[i]": function(user){
            user.isDeleted = ko.observable(false);
        }
    }
};

viewmodel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(model,options));
```

I can successfully bind data to my view model using ko.viewmodel:
plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/afr9B8lPe1W3jCTrfH3w?p=preview

However, when I try to extend the viewmodel, so that the click-toggling behavior is also present, it fails with the messages:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with:
>   function(){return FavoritesVm }"    Message: Unable to process binding
>   "foreach: function (){return favorites() }"   Message: Unable to
>   process binding "event: function (){return {click:toggleFavorite()} }"
>   Message: toggleFavorite is not defined

Here is my options object, that I tried to use:

```
var myOptions = { 
    extend:{
        "{root}.favorites[i]": function(favorite){
            favorite.toggleFavorite = ko.computed(function() {
              debugger; 
                // self = this;
                // var val = self.isFavorite();
                // self.isFavorite(!val);
                // return favorite;
                var val = this.isFavorite();
                this.isFavorite(!val);
                return favorite;
              }, this);
        }
    } 
};
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1gez79Q0kvPlRUYFcOfS?p=preview

N.B.: There a similar question to this one, on SO, regarding extending ko.viewmodel to add a ko.computed() on the {root}. However, I want to add a method to each {root}.favorite[i]. See 
[How can I map a field computed using ko.viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083875/how-can-i-map-a-field-computed-using-ko-viewmodel)  and
http://jsfiddle.net/sublimejs/L6Wm3/8/

Comment: I was able to fix your plunker by referencing the parent here http://plnkr.co/edit/XbJTkr31ZTCt2YnMI4cC?p=preview

Comment: ? The plnkr at the link you quote doesn't work. The goal is to toggle the graphics contained in the red-bordered div's by clicking on them (of course, also toggling the underlying view model property, .isFavorite()). The plnkr at the following link I gave exhibits the correct toggling behavior, however it is using a completely manually created view model. I want to get this working by using a view model made with ko.viewmodel, together with some hand-coded extension.
http://plnkr.co/edit/LEwQd544rxrzhNyoyO5F?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're mapping directly the `favorites` array, not the `FavoritesVm`, so, what you can't specify `{root}.favorites[i]`, because you're in `favorites` context, and not in the `FavoritesVm` context. (i.e. that code tries to find a `favorites` property inside the `favorites` themselves)

So, to specify that you want to modify each element in `favorites`, you simply has to sepcify "[i]":

```
var myOptions = { 
  extend:{"[i]": function(f) {
      f.toggleFavorite = function() {
        f.isFavorite(!f.isFavorite());
      }
    }
  } 
};
```

*NOTE: besides you use too much code for a simple task, you can simply toggle the value as shown in my code, i.e. `f.isFavorite(!f.isFavorite());`*

[Click to see the working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E1aps7bLJkAwvLi4fPjv?p=preview)